# XML signature validation fails in java

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, xml-signature

I have a Digitally Signed XML file and Public Certificate of signer, I want to validate the signature. Original content of response xml is returning false but when I modify the xml it returns true. My java code is as following :-

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.DOMValidateContext;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
public class SignatureVerifierOneFile {
  public static void main(String[] args){       
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());       
        //Signed xml path
        String signedXmlPath = "C:/signedXML.xml";      
        SignatureVerifierOneFile signatureVerifier = new SignatureVerifierOneFile();
        boolean signatureStatus = 
signatureVerifier.verify(signedXmlPath,"C:/Cert.cer");
        System.out.println("xml signature validateionis " + signatureStatus);

    }
    public boolean verify(String signedXml,String publicKeyFile) {

        boolean verificationResult = false;

        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(signedXml);
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");
            if (nl.getLength() == 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find Signature element");
            }

            XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

            DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(getCertificateFromFile(publicKeyFile).getPublicKey(), nl.item(0));
            XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);

            verificationResult = signature.validate(valContext);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while verifying digital siganature" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return verificationResult;
    }

    private X509Certificate getCertificateFromFile(String certificateFile) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
            fis = new FileInputStream(certificateFile);
            return (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(fis);
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My original Signed XML is as following:-

```
<OTPResp resCode="25f341e7-8c72-47a6-b49b-46732e7b8494" status="1" ts="2016-03-31T10:54:07.575" txn="20160331052355192"><AadhaarResp>PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9InllcyI/PjxBZ2VudE90cFJlc3AgcmV0PSJ5IiB0cz0iMjAxNi0wMy0zMVQxMDo1NzoxMi41MzYrMDU6MzAiIGNvZGU9IjZkZjZhZTY1YzMwNjQzMmVhZTkyNzljYTgxZGNkNmJjIiB0eG49IjI1ZjM0MWU3LThjNzItNDdhNi1iNDliLTQ2NzMyZTdiODQ5NCIvPg==</AadhaarResp><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></CanonicalizationMethod><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></SignatureMethod><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>vOND//Y2bsHBIkxkUfjH3d/CYC4=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>HJG1vPQ4CSycCJ4B065faSeBaHGad9XYDUCOj9a/Fa/bWUUFYOpi9/jxVRCngSJACEIEVwUfcCKs9uUEr3DPcDiTB1UqM9BwUCVL28Tghn/HUSg53IQZziDrI3Ta2VyB7oHEoE/8cloArAbu44gDL/selJDD4ZtAsLAecO3NFiugMG3okV7hGcX50lIDm1on7ziFTxFfL1215gmcCfwJhF/zKI0GVBV6FcCDZxLeY7qMGp0Mj4EzicQm1LIZDHIfVskh97NrWi3MKBAv9dPGOevB3XaVw7dt9nct1VEirZaprM/dl5frCDTuwtmNlZN01dnBGHDCRi/+534mvN4oUQ==</SignatureValue></Signature></OTPResp>
```

Mofidied XML which I am able to validate is as following

```
<OTPResp resCode="25f341e7-8c72-47a6-b49b-46732e7b8494" status="1" ts="2016-03-31T10:54:07.575" txn="20160331052355192"><AadhaarResp>PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9InllcyI/PjxBZ2VudE90cFJlc3AgcmV0PSJ5IiB0cz0iMjAxNi0wMy0zMVQxMDo1NzoxMi41MzYrMDU6MzAiIGNvZGU9IjZkZjZhZTY1YzMwNjQzMmVhZTkyNzljYTgxZGNkNmJjIiB0eG49IjI1ZjM0MWU3LThjNzItNDdhNi1iNDliLTQ2NzMyZTdiODQ5NCIvPg==</AadhaarResp><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></CanonicalizationMethod>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></SignatureMethod>
<Reference URI="">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod>
<DigestValue>vOND//Y2bsHBIkxkUfjH3d/CYC4=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>
HJG1vPQ4CSycCJ4B065faSeBaHGad9XYDUCOj9a/Fa/bWUUFYOpi9/jxVRCngSJACEIEVwUfcCKs
9uUEr3DPcDiTB1UqM9BwUCVL28Tghn/HUSg53IQZziDrI3Ta2VyB7oHEoE/8cloArAbu44gDL/se
lJDD4ZtAsLAecO3NFiugMG3okV7hGcX50lIDm1on7ziFTxFfL1215gmcCfwJhF/zKI0GVBV6FcCD
ZxLeY7qMGp0Mj4EzicQm1LIZDHIfVskh97NrWi3MKBAv9dPGOevB3XaVw7dt9nct1VEirZaprM/d
l5frCDTuwtmNlZN01dnBGHDCRi/+534mvN4oUQ==
</SignatureValue>
</Signature></OTPResp>
```

I an unable to figure out what I am doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at your XML documents, the only difference that looks significant to me is the actual `<SignatureValue>` content. While it is identical in terms of Base64 sequence, note that in your modified XML it contains line breaks.

Looking through the XML DSIG spec, we find this: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-SignatureValue

> The SignatureValue element contains the actual value of the digital signature; it is always encoded using base64 [MIME]

It then references RFC 2045. Here's the link: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt

Going through section 6.8, which specifies the Base64 encoding, it mentions:

> The encoded output stream must be represented in lines of no more
>      than 76 characters each.

And that's exactly what you did in your modified XML. Turning the XML into a DOM, the text content of elements is retained exactly as in the input document, including line breaks. My guess is that the Base64 decoder used by the Java XML crypto packages adheres strictly to the spec, and fails to completely parse the signature in your original XML document.

I suggest that after obtaining your `XMLSignature` in method `verify`, you try calling `getSignatureValue()` on it. This should give you an `XMLSignature.SignatureValue`. Try getting the byte array from it. If it's empty, cuts off too soon of getting the `XMLSignature.SignatureValue` failes entirely, the above is probably the issue.

Comment: @ G_H I agree with you "The encoded output stream must be represented in lines of no more than 76 characters each", actually the verification source is correct the problem was in read mechanism of signedXML, while reading signedXML it was dropping newline character.